# NoSuchMethodException with "select new" after upgrading to Spring Data JPA 1.10.3

Tags: spring-data-jpa, openjpa

I encountered an issue after upgrading our Spring Data JPA from 1.9.2 to 1.10.3.

I have the following repository:

```
public interface ShipmentStatisticRepository extends JpaRepository<Shipment, Long> {

    ...

    @Query("select new de.l.b.model.dto.shipment.ShipmentStatistic(s.createdYmd, count(distinct s.oid), count(op), sum(op.price)) " +
            "from Shipment s " +
            "join s.orderPosition op " +
            "where s.created between ?1 and ?2 " +
            "group by s.createdYmd")
    List<ShipmentStatistic> findPerDayBetweenCreated(Date from, Date to);

    ...
}
```

When I call this method I get the following Exception:

```
 org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not instantiate Collection type: org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingResultList; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate Collection type: org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingResultList
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(DefaultJpaDialect.java:122)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:436)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy154.findPerDayBetweenCreated(Unknown Source)
    at de.l.b.hazelcast.map.ShipmentStatisticPerDayMapLoader.getShipmentStatistic(ShipmentStatisticPerDayMapLoader.java:40)
    at de.l.b.hazelcast.map.AbstractShipmentStatisticMapLoader.load(AbstractShipmentStatisticMapLoader.java:38)
    at de.l.b.hazelcast.map.AbstractShipmentStatisticMapLoader.loadAll(AbstractShipmentStatisticMapLoader.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapStoreWrapper.loadAll(MapStoreWrapper.java:143)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.mapstore.AbstractMapDataStore.loadAll(AbstractMapDataStore.java:56)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.mapstore.writebehind.WriteBehindStore.loadAll(WriteBehindStore.java:205)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.BasicRecordStoreLoader.loadAndGet(BasicRecordStoreLoader.java:170)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.BasicRecordStoreLoader.doBatchLoad(BasicRecordStoreLoader.java:143)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.BasicRecordStoreLoader.loadValuesInternal(BasicRecordStoreLoader.java:129)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.BasicRecordStoreLoader.access$100(BasicRecordStoreLoader.java:54)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.BasicRecordStoreLoader$GivenKeysLoaderTask.call(BasicRecordStoreLoader.java:112)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CompletableFutureTask.run(CompletableFutureTask.java:67)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate Collection type: org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingResultList
    at org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createCollection(CollectionFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createCollection(CollectionFactory.java:151)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor.processResult(ResultProcessor.java:146)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:119)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingResultList
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createCollection(CollectionFactory.java:204)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingResultList.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    ... 40 more
```

It looks like the repository can't resolve the correct constructor to fill my projection. With version 1.9.2 everything works fine.

This is my projection class:

```
public class ShipmentStatistic implements Serializable {

    private Date date;
    private long totalParcelsSent;
    private long totalPositionsSent;
    private long totalValue;

    public ShipmentStatistic(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
        this.totalPositionsSent = 0;
        this.totalParcelsSent = 0;
        this.totalValue = 0;
    }

    public ShipmentStatistic(Date date, long totalParcelsSent, long totalPositionsSent, long totalValue) {
        this.date = date;
        this.totalPositionsSent = totalPositionsSent;
        this.totalParcelsSent = totalParcelsSent;
        this.totalValue = totalValue;
    }

    public ShipmentStatistic add(ShipmentStatistic other) {
        this.totalPositionsSent += other.totalPositionsSent;
        this.totalParcelsSent += other.totalParcelsSent;
        this.totalValue += other.totalValue;

        return this;
    }

    // getter and setter
}
```

I made a random shot and tried to add a default constructor but without success.

I can not see my error especially the only change a made was the framework update. We use OpenJPA 2.2.2 as Persistence API by the way. I upgraded to the current version 2.4.1 but this had no effect either.

Any suggestions? May this be a bug in Spring Data JPA in combination with OpenJPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From stacktrace, it looks like openjpa is searching for the default constructor. Could you try adding default constructor explicitly in **ShipmentStatistic.java**?

JPA specification mandates the use of default no-argument constructor.
http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_pc.html#jpa_overview_pc_no_arg

Comment: I tried that because I suspected that too but it didn't work. The stacktrace remains the same.

I also tried to change the primitive longs from the constructor signature to Long with no success. Very strange...

Comment: Very strange indeed ! Looks like there are few bugs with "Select new" with 1.10.x versions and there are major changes too in this regard. Reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6583. Not sure if this is your issue, however worth analysing in this regard.

Comment: This looks very similar to may error, yes. 

Ich can not see the entire comment history because the JIRA board seems to be a bit buggy but as mentioned in the last comment of Yuki YOSHIDA I added 'distinct' to my 'select new' queries and this seems to solve my issue!
Maybe the 'group by' from my query causes the problem?
But for now I've a workaround. Thanks for the hint!